# How can I get a Payment Token when using Cybersource SOAP API

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapui, cybersource

So I have a test payment with the Cybersource SOAP API like below but I'm not able to get it to return a payment token that I can use for payments in future without using the credit card details each times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>{{merchant_id}}</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">{{SOAP KEY}}</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.150">
      <merchantID>{{merchant_id}}</merchantID>
      <merchantReferenceCode>kjdhflasjfhlasdjfasdf</merchantReferenceCode>
      <billTo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <street1>1295 Charleston Road</street1>
        <city>Mountain View</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <postalCode>94043</postalCode>
        <country>US</country>
        <email>null@cybersource.com</email>
      </billTo>
      <item id="0">
        <unitPrice>5.00</unitPrice>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
      </item>
      <item id="1">
        <unitPrice>10.00</unitPrice>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </item>
      <purchaseTotals>
        <currency>ZMW</currency>
      </purchaseTotals>
      <card>
        <accountNumber>4111111111111111</accountNumber>
        <expirationMonth>11</expirationMonth>
        <expirationYear>2020</expirationYear>
        <cvNumber>123</cvNumber>
      </card>
      <ccAuthService run="true"/>
    </requestMessage>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your request:

```
<recurringSubscriptionInfo>
        <frequency>on-demand</frequency>
</recurringSubscriptionInfo>
<paySubscriptionCreateService run="true"/>
```

Your new request will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>{{merchantID}}</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">{{SOAPKey}}</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.150">
      <merchantID>{{merchantID}}</merchantID>
      <merchantReferenceCode>kjdhflasjfhlasdjfasdf</merchantReferenceCode>
      <billTo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <street1>1295 Charleston Road</street1>
        <city>Mountain View</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <postalCode>94043</postalCode>
        <country>US</country>
        <email>null@cybersource.com</email>
      </billTo>
      <item id="0">
        <unitPrice>5.00</unitPrice>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
      </item>
      <item id="1">
        <unitPrice>10.00</unitPrice>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </item>
      <purchaseTotals>
        <currency>ZMW</currency>
      </purchaseTotals>
      <card>
        <accountNumber>4111111111111111</accountNumber>
        <expirationMonth>11</expirationMonth>
        <expirationYear>2020</expirationYear>
        <cvNumber>123</cvNumber>
      </card>
      <recurringSubscriptionInfo>
        <frequency>on-demand</frequency>
      </recurringSubscriptionInfo>
      <ccAuthService run="true"/>
      <paySubscriptionCreateService run="true"/>
    </requestMessage>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response will now have a subscriptionID in it, that is your token to use in place of the card account number. You might find the [tokenization guide](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payment_Tokenization/SO_API/Payment_Tokenization_SO_API.pdf) useful.

You should not expose your merchantID and SOAP Key here. Please edit your question to remove them.

Comment: Your welcome Richard. Can you mark this as the answer?